# Get order value on completed checkout

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm using drupal 6 and ubercart 6.x-2.9

I've created my own template for the checkout complete page, this is so I can install conversion tracking code from adwords.

I'd like to pull the order value and insert it into the adwords snippet.

Does anyone know how to call this value?  Is there already a variable with the correct value that I can just echo/print into my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pull the order value using the following code

```
$order = uc_order_load(intval($_SESSION['cart_order']));

if ($order)
{
   $amt = round($order->order_total,2);
}
```